# XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x00\x00\x00\x01Bud1'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos, xlrd

I am trying to consolidate a few excel files and getting the following error.

NOTE: This code works fine in windows, I am trying to run the same on mac and im getting this error.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os


all_data=pd.DataFrame() <br/>
temp1=pd.DataFrame()<br/>
temp2=pd.DataFrame()

FL=os.listdir("Files/")

for i in FL:<br/>
    temp1=pd.read_excel("Files/"+i)<br/>
    print("Reading file "+ i)<br/>
    temp1.loc[:, "Sub Query"] = i[0:i.find(".")]<br/>
    print("working on file "+ i)<br/>
    temp2 = pd.concat([temp2,temp1], sort=False)<br/>
    print("file "+ i +" is over, moving on...")<br/>

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output/Mastersheet.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False})<br/>
temp2.to_excel(writer, index=False)<br/>
writer.close()<br/>


**Error:**

 File "<ipython-input-9-1e7da69236eb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/simplify360/Desktop/TVS/Consolidate/consolidate.py', wdir='/Users/simplify360/Desktop/TVS/Consolidate')

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/simplify360/Desktop/TVS/Consolidate/consolidate.py", line 19, in <module>
    temp1=pd.read_excel("Files/"+i)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 310, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 359, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x00\x00\x00\x01Bud1'
```

I have tried different things like removing few fields from the excel file, renaming the excel file but it still won't work. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Hey sai, can you do `print(FL)` and post the output here, I have a feeling you have non excel files you are trying to read with excel hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same issue and I just solved it. The problem is that there is a hidden file called '.DS_Store' in every directory on Macs. Try changing this block of code:

```
for i in FL:<br/>
    temp1=pd.read_excel("Files/"+i)<br/>
    print("Reading file "+ i)<br/>
    temp1.loc[:, "Sub Query"] = i[0:i.find(".")]<br/>
    print("working on file "+ i)<br/>
    temp2 = pd.concat([temp2,temp1], sort=False)<br/>
    print("file "+ i +" is over, moving on...")<br/>
```

To this:

```
for i in FL:<br/>
    if(i != '.DS_Store'):
        temp1=pd.read_excel("Files/"+i)<br/>
        print("Reading file "+ i)<br/>
        temp1.loc[:, "Sub Query"] = i[0:i.find(".")]<br/>
        print("working on file "+ i)<br/>
        temp2 = pd.concat([temp2,temp1], sort=False)<br/>
        print("file "+ i +" is over, moving on...")<br/>
```